React with .NET Core Api - Cognito
I have created a React front end which will be calling into a set of .NET Core Apis.  The application uses AWS Cognito as its Identity Provider.  I would like to login the user, get an access token, and then pass that access token in the Auth headers as part of every .NET Core Api call.
In the Azure world, there is an MSAL library which helps to make the whole login and fetching token process a lot easier.  Is there an AWS counterpart to this?
I have tried researching the right approach on AWS but it doesn't seem straightforward and I can't really find many examples of this.

So AWS Amplify is your one stop solution here.

First, install the @aws-amplify/ui-react library as well as aws-amplify if you have not already:
npm install aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react


Next, open src/App.js and add the Authenticator.
import React from 'react';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}

This will add an Authenticator UI component to your app as shown below.


Now, provide your App with Amplify configurations. In your app's entry point (specifically App.js, index.js, _app.js, or main.js), write the following code.
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      //  Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
      userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',
      // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
      userPoolClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',
    }
  }
});


Next refer this answer to learn how to retrieve AccessToken and IDToken using Amplify library.


References

https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator
https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/react/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/


I have created a video on similar topic here for Angular. If needed, refer to Implementing Amazon Cognito Authentication in Angular using AWS Amplify

